# Copy specific rows from another sheet based on a value

Tags: excel, vba

On one sheet I have information of my clients and the guaranties I have for them in the following way (some clients have more than one). On another sheet I have the clients that have debt currently and I want a macro that imports the guaranties the client has, for each loan they have outstanding.

I'm clueless as to how to do this which is why I'm asking for help. This is fairly complicated so recording the macro wont work.

For example:

Sheet 1

Column 1        Column 2

John  --------- Mortgage

John  --------- Cash Collateral

Jose  --------- Cash Collateral

Sportia --------- Accounts receivables

Sportia --------- Cash Collateral

Sportia --------- Mortgage

Sheet 2

Column 1          Column 2

John              Loan 1

Sportia           Loan 1

Sportia           Loan 2

Sportia           Loan 2

The outcome should be like this:

Column 1          Column 2    Column 3

John              Loan 1      Mortgage

John              Loan 1      Cash Collateral

Sportia           Loan 1      Accounts receivables

Sportia           Loan 1      Cash Collateral

Sportia           Loan 1      Mortgage

Sportia           Loan 2      Accounts receivables

Sportia           Loan 2      Cash Collateral

Sportia           Loan 2      Mortgage

Sportia           Loan 3      Accounts receivables

Sportia           Loan 3      Cash Collateral

Sportia           Loan 3      Mortgage

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get your questions right, but couldn't you just solve that with a vlookup() if you have single entries for the loans or a sumifs() if they are split to multiple rows.